# MVC 5 related to views settings for grid acc. to view indexing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list where I am getting all data approx. 50 columns with foreign key tables data through a model.
    my second list where I am getting only columnname in rows approx. 10 columname,it can be more acc. to condition ,

now I want to bind a table using 2nd table column name and data will come from first list..because that columns are available in 1st list..so I want only those column name using mvc.. is it possible ?

note : I am using this things for viewsettings acc. to diff. diff. view which we are creating ...so please tell me how can I map rows of 2nd list with column of 1st list using mvc query...